# Can I create a shallow repository copy with svnsync?

Tags: svn, svnsync

There's a repo online that has 13k commits, but I'm only interested in last 1000 of them. Is it possible to copy them with svnsync?

I want to be able to checkout within the last 1000 commits from this local repository, and it should be faster than from the server

Revision numbers must be preserved.
`svnsync` must be able to sync the future revisions normally into the local repository.

Comment: Copy them to where? Replicate to another repository? Get a dump stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example I save last 45 commits of a repo. The helper python script is below.

```
# svnsync 1.6.11
# rhel 6 x86_64

# params
svn_baserepourl="http://svn.igniterealtime.org/svn/repos"
svn_subdir="spark/trunk"
reponame=spark
skipuntil=13774


# well-known svnsync preparation
repopath=`pwd`/$reponame.svn
svnadmin create "$repopath"

echo '#!/bin/sh' >"$repopath"/hooks/pre-revprop-change
chmod +x "$repopath"/hooks/pre-revprop-change

svnsync init file://"$repopath" "$svn_baserepourl/$svn_subdir"

expectedfmt="4
layout sharded 1000"

if [ x"$expectedfmt" != x"$(cat "$repopath/db/format")" ]; then
    echo unknown db format
fi

# create database folder structure
( cd "$repopath/db" && echo $(for (( i=0; i<=$((skipuntil / 1000)) ; i++ )) ; do mkdir -p revprops/$i revs/$i; done ) )

# don't create last skipped revision
skipuntil=$((skipuntil - 1))

# create dummy revision files
( cd "$repopath/db" && for (( i=0; i<=$skipuntil; i++ )) ; do echo revprops/$((i/1000))/$i; echo revs/$((i/1000))/$i; done | xargs touch )

# update revision counter
echo $skipuntil >"$repopath/db/current"

# we need a valid revision file
cp "$repopath/db/revs/0/0" "$repopath/db/revs/$((skipuntil/1000))/$skipuntil"

# last skipped revision number
skipuntil=$((skipuntil + 1))

if false; then
    # TODO: if svnrdump available
    # mkdir in local repo
    # svnrdump last skipped revision and subdir
    # svnadmin load --parent-dir subdir
    :
else
    # checkout last skipped revision
    rm -rf temptree
    svn co -r $skipuntil "$svn_baserepourl/$svn_subdir" "temptree/$svn_subdir"
    cd temptree
    pushd "$svn_subdir"

    # save properties
    svn proplist --xml -v -R  | ~/svnprops.py >/tmp/propset.sh

    # remove .svn folders
    find . -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf

    popd

    # checkout our copy
    svn co "file://$repopath" .

    # add the files
    svn add --no-ignore --force .

    # delete automatic props
    for p in $(svn proplist -q -R | sort -u); do svn propdel -q -R $p; done

    # restore original props
    pushd "$svn_subdir"
    sh /tmp/propset.sh
    popd

    # commit the last skipped revision
    svn commit -m"shallow root"

    cd ..
    rm -rf temptree
fi

# update svnsync counters
svn propset --revprop -r 0 svn:sync-last-merged-rev $skipuntil  "file://$repopath"
svn propset --revprop -r 0 svn:sync-currently-copying $((skipuntil+1))  "file://$repopath"

# sync!
svnsync sync "file://$repopath"
```

This is some old svnprops.py to copy svn properties between repos:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import xml.sax
import xml.sax.handler

"""
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<properties>
<target
   path="file:///.snapshots/persist/builds/cyg-apt/cyg-apt.svn/trunk">
<property
   name="svn:ignore">build
</property>
</target>
</properties>
"""

class Subhandler:
  def __init__(self, mainHandler, parenthandler):
    self.mainHandler = mainHandler
    self.parenthandler = parenthandler
    self.subhandler = None
    self.lvl = 0
  def startElement(self, name, attributes):
    self.lvl = self.lvl + 1
  def characters(self, data):
    pass
  def endElement(self, name):
    self.lvl = self.lvl - 1

class Subhandler_properties(Subhandler):
  def startElement(self, name, attributes):
    pass
  def characters(self, data):
    pass
  def endElement(self, name):
    pass

class P1ropertiesDocHandler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
  def __init__(self):
    self.subhandler = None

  def startElement(self, name, attributes):
    if subhandler != None:
      subhandler.startElement(name, attributes)
    elif name == "properties":
      Subhandler_properties(self)

  def endElement(self, name):
    if subhandler != None:
      subhandler.endElement(name)

  def characters(self, data):
    if subhandler != None:
      subhandler.characters(data)


class PropertiesDocHandler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
  def __init__(self):
    self.target = None
    self.property = None

  def startElement(self, name, attributes):
    if name == "target":
      self.target = attributes["path"]
    elif name == "property":
      self.property = attributes["name"]
      self.propval = ""

  def endElement(self, name):
    if name == "target":
      self.target = None
    elif name == "property":
      print("svn ps \"" + self.property.replace("\"","\\\"") + "\" \"" + self.propval.replace("\"","\\\"") + "\" \"" + self.target.replace("\"","\\\"") + "\"")
      self.property = None
      self.propval = None

  def characters(self, data):
    if self.property != None:
      self.propval += data

parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
handler = PropertiesDocHandler()
parser.setContentHandler(handler)
#print("aa\"ass".replace("\"","\\\""))
parser.parse(sys.stdin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy these last 1000 revisions where? `svnsync` tool is used for repository replication, not 'copying' revisions. If you  want to get last 1000 revisions remotely, use [`svnrdump` tool](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnrdump) where you can specify revision range.

Comment: I want fast checkouts within the last 1000 commits

Comment: And then do what with them? You won't be able to commit back to the original repository from those working copies.

Comment: `svnrdump` can do part of the job. Updated my answer. Open question is how to quickly increase the revision number of local repo.